# How can I filter tf.data.Dataset by specific values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I create a dataset by reading the TFRecords, I map the values and I want to filter the dataset for specific values, but since the result is a dict with tensors, I am not able to get the actual value of a tensor or to check it with `tf.cond()` / `tf.equal`. How can I do that?

```
def mapping_func(serialized_example):
    feature = { 'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.string) }
    features = tf.parse_single_example(serialized_example, features=feature)
    return features

def filter_func(features):
    # this doesn't work
    #result = features['label'] == 'some_label_value'
    # neither this
    result = tf.reshape(tf.equal(features['label'], 'some_label_value'), [])
    return result

def main():
    file_names = ["/var/data/file1.tfrecord", "/var/data/file2.tfrecord"]
    dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(file_names)
    dataset = dataset.map(mapping_func)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
    dataset = dataset.filter(filter_func)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    sample = iterator.get_next()
```

Comment: Which error do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am answering my own question. I found the issue!

What I needed to do is `tf.unstack()` the label like this:

```
label = tf.unstack(features['label'])
label = label[0]
```

before I give it to `tf.equal()`:

```
result = tf.reshape(tf.equal(label, 'some_label_value'), [])
```

I suppose the problem was that the label is defined as an array with one element of type string `tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.string)`, so in order to get the first and single element I had to unpack it (which creates a list) and then get the element with index 0, correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to make label a 1-dimensional array in the first place.

with:

```
feature = {'label': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string)}
```

you won't need to unstack the label in your filter_func

Answer (score 1):

Reading, filtering a dataset is very easy and there is no need to unstack anything.

to read the dataset:

```
print(my_dataset, '\n\n')
##let us print the first 3 records
for record in my_dataset.take(3):
    ##below could be large in case of image
    print(record)
    ##let us print a specific key
    print(record['key2'])
```

To filter is equally simple:

```
my_filtereddataset = my_dataset.filter(_filtcond1)
```

where you define _filtcond1 however you want. Let us say there is a 'true' 'false' boolean flag in your dataset, then:

```
@tf.function
def _filtcond1(x):
    return x['key_bool'] == 1
```

or even a lambda function:

```
my_filtereddataset = my_dataset.filter(lambda x: x['key_int']>13)
```

If you are reading a dataset which you havent created or you are unaware of the keys (as seems to be the OPs case), you can use this to get an idea of the keys and structure first:

```
import json
from google.protobuf.json_format import MessageToJson

for raw_record in noidea_dataset.take(1):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
    ##print(example) ##if image it will be toooolong
    m = json.loads(MessageToJson(example))
    print(m['features']['feature'].keys())
```

Now you can proceed with the filtering

Answer (score -6):

You should try to use the apply function from 
tf.data.TFRecordDataset [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset)

Otherwise... read this article about TFRecords to get a better knowledge about TFRecords  [TFRecords for humans](https://planspace.org/20170323-tfrecords_for_humans/)

But the most likely situation is that you can not access neither modify a TFRecord...there is a request on github about this topic [TFRecords request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7482)

My advice is to make the things as easy as you can...you have to know that you are you working with graph and sessions...

In any case...if everything fail try the part of the code that does not work in a tensorflow session as simple as you can do it...probably all these operations should be done when tf.session is running...